# Rerender page after login in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I have Login page Component and i want to rerender page after successfully login.
My **App.js** File:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {loginStatus: "0"};
}
componentDidMount(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("user_id")){
        this.setState({ loginStatus: "1" });
    }
}
  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
             <div>
                <Route path="/" exact render={(props) => {
                    if(this.state.loginStatus === "1")
                        return <Dashboard />;
                    else
                        return <Login />;
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
 }
}

export default App;
```

And My Login.js is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { Input, Card, Icon, Button, Form, message } from 'antd';
const axios = require('axios');

class LoginPage extends Component {
handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
    if (!err) {
        axios.get('http://mybackendsite.com/api/login', {
            params: {
                mobile: "986541123331",
                password: "123456789"
            }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            if(response.data.response === "wrong"){
                console.log("password is wrong");
            }else{
                console.log("password is true and logged in successfully");

                //SOME CODE TO RERENDER PAGE AND SHOW DASHBOARD
                reRenderApp(); //sample function
            }

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("err is:" + error);
        })
    }
});
  }
  render() {
      //SOME ELEMENTS
 }
```

I need a function (for example : reRenderApp() ) to rerender page and show dashboard to logged in user.
i can use window.location.reload but I do not want to do this. I want rerender page without refresh.
how I can do this?

Comment: You could create a method called e.g. `changeLoginStatus` in `App` that updates the `loginStatus` in the state. You could then pass down this method as a prop to `LoginPage` and then call it when the login is successful, and `App` will be re-rendered.

Comment: @Tholle how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways that you can do this is with the help of a callback function.

You can pass on a prop from the App.js to Login.js and then as soon as the API returns the login status you can call that callback prop function where you just change the state of the loginStatus.

These are the few changes that can get the work done for you.

In App.js

```
return (
  <Login
    onSuccess={() => {
      this.setState({ loginStatus: true });
    }}
  />
);
```

In Login.js

```
//SOME CODE TO RERENDER PAGE AND SHOW DASHBOARD
this.props.onSuccess();
```

This is all that you need to do to make the Login page component to rerender and show the dashboard page.

Hope so this answer will solve your problem.

Comment: error : "this is undefined" For this line ( this.props.onSuccess() )

Comment: Check if you are calling the handleSubmit function the right way or else you can place the api call in another function and then do the same.
Or you can follow this link to get a clue of how to make api call in a better way. See the post request, https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/